# appending to a vstack out of a for loop

Tags: python, astronomy

I have multiple images of a star field that I extract information from. I want to create a data cube who's first two dimensions are the pixel coordinates and information, and the 3rd dimension are the subsequent images. The first image is the first slice, and so on.

The function I use looks at the image, decides where a star is, writes down its coordinates and intensity information, and puts it into an array. I want my program to use the same coordinates as the first image on the subsequent images, recalculate the intensity information, and for each loop append these new results to the data cube, adding a new slice each time.

Here's what I've written:

```
#above imports the first image, and applies function fitPSF to it, which returns:
results_array = [x2, y2, amplitude, intensity, sigma_y_fitted, sigma_x_fitted]

#want first image to be first slice in data cube
data_cube = np.vstack((results_array,))

#load image captures
images = [imageio.imread("/home/jryan/"+str(i + 1)+'capture.PNG', as_gray=True) for i in range(5)]

#loop through 5 frames
for i in images:        
#define coordinates to fit a psf to 
    x,y = results_array[0],results_array[1]
    #fitpsf
    x2, y2, amplitude, intensity, sigma_y_fitted, sigma_x_fitted = fitPSF(image_array, global_mean, x, y)
    new_results = [x2, y2, amplitude, intensity, sigma_y_fitted, sigma_x_fitted]
    
    #append new results to data cube
    data_cube = np.vstack((results_array,new_results))
    np.append(data_cube,new_results)
```

The error i am getting right now is

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 149 and the array at index 1 has size 147,
```

and I can't pinpoint why. Right now I am using the exact same image 6 times, so the sizes should be compatible.

Also I believe that when each new_results is being appended to data_cube,it isn't being interpreted as a new slice in the data cube, but rather is just being appended to the 2D results array. Is append the right module to be trying to do this? or is there an error in the process I am using?

Comment: What are the shapes of the outputs of fitPSF?  Are x2, y2, amplitude, intensity, sigma_y_fitted, sigma_x_fitted all scalars?

Comment: Yes, they are all scalars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some numpy functions do unexpected things if the `axis` in the arguments is not provided explicitly even if it does what you usually want most of the time without it.  With `np.append` it does [two things you may not want it to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

1. If you do not specify the axis argument, it flattens the inputs!
2. It creates a new copy of your array each time.

After the first pass, `data_cube` is a 1-D array.

---

For me, I like to accumulate each "row" into a list, and then call `np.stack` once and provide the axis that I would want to be time dimension in your case.  This is my best guess:

```
#above imports the first image, and applies function fitPSF to it, which returns:
results_array = [x2, y2, amplitude, intensity, sigma_y_fitted, sigma_x_fitted]

#want first image to be first slice in data cube
results_arrays = [np.array(results_array)]

#load image captures
images = [imageio.imread("/home/jryan/"+str(i + 1)+'capture.PNG', as_gray=True) for i in range(5)]

#loop through 5 frames
x,y = results_array[0],results_array[1] #results_array was never modified so these x,y should remain the same throughout the loop
for i in images:        
    #fitpsf
    new_results = fitPSF(image_array, global_mean, x, y)
    results_arrays.append(np.array(new_results)) # this is a list append, not np.append

data_cube = np.stack(results_arrays, axis=-1) # assuming you want the last axis to be time

---
# or in one line:

x, y = results_array[:2]
data_cube = np.stack([np.array(results_array)]+ list(map(lambda img: np.array(fitPSF(img, global_mean, x, y)),  images)), axis=-1)
```

Comment: could you elaborate in the first method in the last line, why you write axis=-1?

Comment: Also now in the last line where you define the data cube, I get the error 'all input arrays must have the same shape'. Should they not have the same shape already? Is the new_results array a different size from the first results_array?

Comment: It is shorthand for "use the last axis."  Stack adds a new axis.  Assuming that each results_array is an array with six elements, then the shape of each array is (6), so it only has one axis.  By setting axis=-1, it is the same thing as saying axis=1 (because axis=0, the first axis is your data dimension).   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Comment: Since I don't have your data, what happens if you run: for arr in results_array: print(arr.shape) just before the data_cube assignment line?

Comment: it just says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Im sorry! Im not familiar with this function - I assume it calculates a point spread function of the optics, but no clue what library it comes from or the function signature.

Comment: No problem, thanks for all the help thus far!